# How to add hyphenations for a field in markup?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, haml

There is a field(`auth_public_key`) whose value may go beyond the markup:

```
  - if @connection.auth_public_key.present?
    %el-row.m-b-10
      %el-col.p-t-15.p-b-15.p-l-20.p-r-20{":span": "24"}
        %span= @connection.auth_public_key
```

**Q**: how can I add hyphens depending on the length? smth like `overflow-wrap: break-word;`

What is happening now:

```
Field value: aaaaaaaaa
I expect: aaa\naaa\naaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with next solution:

Change code in my .haml file

```
  %el-col.p-t-15.p-b-15.p-l-20.p-r-20
    %code= @connection.auth_public_key
```

After this added in common.scss file

```
// Code 
code {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```